# spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for all()

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm getting the above error when I want to mock http REST services created using Restangular.
Here's my piece of code:

```
var someParameter = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Length" }]
   spyOn(Restangular, 'one').and.callThrough();
    it('expect company service to be called', function () {     
        httpBackend.expectGET('http://localhost:8283/com/companies', {
            someParameter: someParameter
        }).respond(mockToReturn);
    });
```

Has anybody encountered the same issue.And any fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did it, hope it helps.

```
var Restangular;
beforeEach(inject(function( _Restangular_) {
    Restangular = _Restangular_;
    spyOn(Restangular, 'all').and.callThrough();
}));
```

Comment: Trying to use `inject` and it is near impossible to debug because there is no explanation as to what it is or why to use it.

Comment: For reference: it is [`angular.mock.inject`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should rather invoke spyOn inside function passed to "it"

```
var someParameter = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Length" }]
it('expect company service to be called', function () {
  spyOn(Restangular, 'one').and.callThrough();
  httpBackend.expectGET('http://localhost:8283/com/companies', {
    someParameter: someParameter
  }).respond(mockToReturn);
});
```

Comment: No, spies should be added in a `beforeEach`